# Largest possible number of student passed in all three subject

Tags: combinatorics, self-learning

**Question:**

From $50$ students taking examination in Mathematics, Physics and Chemistry, $37$ passed in mathematics, $24$ passed in physics and $43$ passed in chemistry. At most $19$ students passed in mathematics and physics, at most $29$ passed in mathematics and chemistry and at most $20$ passed in physics and chemistry.

The largest number of students passed in all the three subjects are?

**My Efforts:**

In this type of problem i find it easier to solve with Venn Diagram.

[image]

I Don't know what to do ahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use inclusion/exclusion: $50-37-24-43+19+29+20-X=0$.

Now find $X$...

Your *Venn Diagram* is an equivalent solution if you put:

- $[37,24,43]$ in the big circles
- $[19,29,20]$ in the smaller ellipses
- $[X]$ in the smallest intersection area

Comment: But can't we do this by Venn Diagram?

Comment: I got this method and answer is 14, but i want to do it by Venn Diagram method, Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: @hey: That Venn Diagram is an equivalent solution. Put $37,24,43$ in those big circles, $19,29,20$ in those smaller ellipses, and $X$ in the smallest intersection area.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Nope it's 14. I think you missed something!

Comment: yes $14$ is right. it is from the restriction of the total number $50$